# How to use reportlab on GAE(Google App Engine)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, zlib, python-imaging-library, reportlab

I have read [how to use reportlab with google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606060/how-to-use-reportlab-with-google-app-engine) but it's not help for me. Currently, I have a working version on my local environment and try to deploy to GAE.

But there is error when the deployment try to install pillow:

`ValueError: zlib is required unless explicitly disabled using --disable-zlib, aborting`

I looked for some solutions ([Fail during installation of Pillow (Python module) in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34631806/fail-during-installation-of-pillow-python-module-in-linux)), but I cannot install zlib by either installing `zlib1g-dev` or `pip install CFLAGS="--disable-zlab"

How should I install reportlab on GAE properly? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally I downgrade the version of reportlab to 2.7 to make it work.